# Dart Polymer core-selector multiple selection binding to selected not working

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm using the `core-selector` for multiple selection in this way:

```dart
    <core-selector id="selector" selected={{selected}} valueattr="label" multi>
        <div class="item" label="foo">foo</div>
        <div class="item" label="bar">bar</div>
        <div class="item" label="zot">zot</div>
    </core-selector>
```

I'm binding the selected field to a `List` in order to set and retrieve the selected elements:

```dart
@observable
List<String> selected = toObservable([]);
```

When I print the list with no selection I get an array with one element: an empty array.

```dart
selected: [[]]
```

When I select an element (bar) I get an array with two elements: an empty array and the selected element.

```dart
selected: [[], bar]
```

If I initialize the selected array with an element (zot) when I print it I get:

```dart
selected: [[zot]]
```

Am I using the `core-selector` in the wrong way or there is a bug?

The workaround seems to access programmatically the selected property of core-selector element.

Tested with core_elements 0.4.0+6.

Comment: Looks similar to https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/issues/141

Comment: Not the same. In this case the selection array is modified in a strange way and in some ways reflects the selections.

Comment: I've open an issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/issues/157

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a workaround:

```dart
void ready() {
  $["selector"].selected = selected;
}
```

Where `selected` is the list used to keep the selected items and `selector` the `core-selector` id.